# Bootstrap Range Slider: How to align the thumb (circle) on the left side of the slider track?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, range

I am working on an Angular 6 project where I am using Bootstrap.

**What I am trying to do:**
The user should be able to specify the number of persons for a booking.
This input should be made with a range slider.
The slider should start at 0 with a maximum of 30 persons.

Currently, I added the range slider using this line of HTML:

```
<h3>Value: {{personSliderValue}}</h3>
<input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange" 
               value="0" min="0" max="30" #ref (change)="personSliderOnChange(ref.value)">
```

The output looks like this:
[Current Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTN4X.png)

Because I specified the value="0" property, the slider's initial value is 0 (desired behavior).
The problem is that **the thumb is still located in the middle** of the slider (since the slider ranges from 0 to 30 it currently stands on index 15 whereas the value is 0).
This is a very unnatural behavior and confusing for the user.
When I move the thumb the values get displayed correctly.

**I want to display the thumb at the very left (at index 0) before any user interaction has happened.**

Desired output:
[Desired Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je6y6.png)

How can I modify the thumb's position?

By the way, is there any detailed documentation for Bootstrap Range Sliders?
All I can find is this (which is not very detailed in my opinion): 
[Bootstrap Range](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#range), [Range Inputs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#range-inputs)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reprodices the issue please? When I try it seems to display as you require

Comment: @user184994 Thank you for your quick reply.
What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but just tested in Firefox as well. Here is a StackBlitz where it seems to be working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qldf3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @user184994 Ok
I have tried to recreate the issue using StackBlitz, but somehow it works there.

For me it does not work on my Browsers (--> when using ng serve). Neither with Edge, nor Firefox, nor Chrome.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zonapu)

Comment: Okay, what if you just copy the most basic one you can into your project, e.g. `<input type="range" class="form-control-range" value="0" min="0" max="30">` Does that work?

Comment: @user184994 Yes, that worked.
This also helped me find out the issue. I have integrated this slider into a <form>. Apparently, the formcontrol I am using for this form interfered with the slider, causing it to have an empty string ("") initial value.

With some changes to the formcontrol logic I was able to resolve the issue.
The slider is now working as desired.

Thank you very much for your time and help!